# input_formats in django admin has no effect

Tags: django, admin

I'm trying to use input_foramts in the admin but it has no effect.
What am I doing wrong?

# model
 class Feedback(models.Model):
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# admin form
 class FeedbackAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  created_at = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))
  class Meta:
   model = Feedback

# admin
 class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = FeedbackAdminForm
 admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) like this:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Feedback'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Feedbacks'

    def  __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.created_at)

class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateTimeField: {'input_formats': ('%d/%m/%Y',)},
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your model definition somewhere?

Comment: I did post it in the original question.

Comment: There was a comma missing in the format tuple. I have updated the example.